# populate spinner with some static value which is showing the label as 'select item' in android

Tags: android

i am using a spinner control in my application.i want to set a label on d spinner as "select item" when the page loads.when user trying to select something from the spinner the item should be displayed on the label.is it possible?then how?plz help me

Answer (score 3):

Use android:prompt. See this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html)

```
 <Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"
/>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" ?plz let me knw